# Alterar width do mat tooltip angular

Tags: angular, material-design

Preciso aumentar o width do mat tooltip do angular

[Angular Material Tooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples)
Tentei:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

O padding e a font-size foi aplicado, mas não consigo alterar a largura do tooltip.
Tentei definir um valor fixo para o width, ex: 400px!important ou 100%!important, mas ambos não fizeram diferença. Gostaria que não houvesse quebra de linhas. Alguém sabe como aumentar?

Comment: Aqui colocando o width na mão funcionou, fiz direto pelo devTools pelo link que vc passou ai como vc pode ver no link http://prntscr.com/m2n3v5, mas aqui não tenho ambiente para simular isso... Minha sugestão é que vc coloque `.mat-tooltip { max-width: initial;} ` isso vai fazer como que o texto não quebre dentro do Tooltipe. Se funcionar ai me fala que eu faço uma resposta com mais detalhes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando o exemplo dado na própria [documentação](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/examples), bastou adicionar o width.

**HTML**

```
    mat-form-field class="example-user-input">
  <mat-select placeholder="Tooltip position" [formControl]="position">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let positionOption of positionOptions" [value]="positionOption">
      {{positionOption}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<button mat-raised-button
        matTooltip="Info about the action"
        [matTooltipPosition]="position.value"
        aria-label="Button that displays a tooltip in various positions">
  Action
</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.example-user-input {
  margin-right: 8px;
}

::ng-deep .mat-tooltip {
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 500px; //bastou adicionar isso
}
```